# Chain of ideals in a Noetherian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be a (commutative) Noetherian ring, and let $\{I_n\}$ be a chain of ideals of $R$. As we know, the Noetherian property of $R$ indicates that $\{I_n\}$ satisfies the ascending chain condition, namely, there exists some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
I_{m - 1} \subseteq I_m = I_{m + k} \text{ for all } k \in \mathbb{N}. 
$$
I was wondering given a specific $R$ and specific chain $\{I_n\}$ whether there is any way to determine what this integer $m$ is. At this moment, I cannot construct even one explicit non-trivial example (in particular, I was trying with rings of single variable/multivariable polynomials/power series). Any examples, or any indication towards some general theory or reference material will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you want someone to come up with a chain of ideals that “looks” infinite at first, but which you can inspect to find a spot where it becomes stationary?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, pretty much. Honestly, I have used this Noetherian property many times, but never once paused to observe that the property (as written in elementary algebra books) is only qualitative, but not quantitative. I am now trying to see if there is some literature studying this....

Comment: I suppose it's a valid request, but it doesn't seem practical.  I've never used an example like that at least. But maybe in computational algebra it is actually useful..